# Nifi RecordReader & RecordWriter serialization error. IllegalTypeConversionException; Cannot convert value of class; because the type is not supported

Tags: avro, apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to convert json to json using JoltTransformRecord in Apache Nifi. When I try transform json in https://jolt-demo.appspot.com/, I'm getting correct result. This is okey.

But, when I'm trying to transform json using JoltTransformRecord, it is throws an exception. Error is; **"Cannot convert value of class [Ljava.lang.Object; because the type is not supported"**. But I didn't understand why I'm getting this error. I did check my input and output schemas, but I didn't find anything. They looks like correct.

In the below, my input and output json examples, jolt specification, input and output schemas are given. Also, for this, I'm using **JsonTreeReader** and **JsonRecordSetWriter**.

--- How can I solve this problem? ---

**Example input json** for `JoltTransformRecord`(In this example, there is only one json object inside array. But actually, there are a lot of json object inside array.);

```
[ {
  "uuid" : "MFMS1-MC5",
  "componentId" : "path1",
  "Samples" : {
    "PathFeedrate" : [ {
      "dataItemId" : "pf",
      "timestamp" : "2019-03-01T21:48:27.940558Z",
      "sequence" : "68104",
      "value" : "425.5333",
      "name" : "Fact",
      "subType" : "ACTUAL"
    }, {
      "dataItemId" : "pf",
      "timestamp" : "2019-03-01T21:48:30.244219Z",
      "sequence" : "68117",
      "value" : "0",
      "name" : "Fact",
      "subType" : "ACTUAL"
    } ]
  },
  "Events" : {
    "SequenceNumber" : [ {
      "dataItemId" : "seq",
      "timestamp" : "2019-03-01T21:48:27.940558Z",
      "sequence" : "68105",
      "value" : "0",
      "name" : "sequenceNum"
    } ],
    "Unit" : [ {
      "dataItemId" : "unit",
      "timestamp" : "2019-03-01T21:48:27.940558Z",
      "sequence" : "68106",
      "value" : "13",
      "name" : "unitNum"
    } ]
  }
}]
```

**Sample output Json I want**;

```
{
  "DataItems" : [ {
    "uuid" : "MFMS1-MC5",
    "componentId" : "path1",
    "eventType" : "Samples",
    "type" : "PathFeedrate",
    "dataItemId" : "pf",
    "timestamp" : "2019-03-01T21:48:27.940558Z",
    "sequence" : "68104",
    "value" : "425.5333",
    "name" : "Fact",
    "subType" : "ACTUAL"
  }, {
    "uuid" : "MFMS1-MC5",
    "componentId" : "path1",
    "eventType" : "Samples",
    "type" : "PathFeedrate",
    "dataItemId" : "pf",
    "timestamp" : "2019-03-01T21:48:30.244219Z",
    "sequence" : "68117",
    "value" : "0",
    "name" : "Fact",
    "subType" : "ACTUAL"
  }, {
    "uuid" : "MFMS1-MC5",
    "componentId" : "path1",
    "eventType" : "Events",
    "type" : "SequenceNumber",
    "dataItemId" : "seq",
    "timestamp" : "2019-03-01T21:48:27.940558Z",
    "sequence" : "68105",
    "value" : "0",
    "name" : "sequenceNum"
  }, {
    "uuid" : "MFMS1-MC5",
    "componentId" : "path1",
    "eventType" : "Events",
    "type" : "Unit",
    "dataItemId" : "unit",
    "timestamp" : "2019-03-01T21:48:27.940558Z",
    "sequence" : "68106",
    "value" : "13",
    "name" : "unitNum"
  } ]
}
```

**My Jolt Specification**;

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Samples": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,uuid)": "Items.&2[#2].uuid",
            "@(3,componentId)": "Items.&2[#2].componentId",
            "$2": "Items.&2[#2].eventType",
            "$1": "Items.&2[#2].type",
            "*": "Items.&2[#2].&"
          }
        }
      },
      "Events": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,uuid)": "Items.&2[#2].uuid",
            "@(3,componentId)": "Items.&2[#2].componentId",
            "$2": "Items.&2[#2].eventType",
            "$1": "Items.&2[#2].type",
            "*": "Items.&2[#2].&"
          }
        }
      },
      "Condition": {
        "*": {
          "*": {
            "@(3,uuid)": "Items.&2[#2].uuid",
            "@(3,componentId)": "Items.&2[#2].componentId",
            "$2": "Items.&2[#2].eventType",
            "$1": "Items.&2[#2].value",
            "*": "Items.&2[#2].&"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Items": {
        "*": {
          "*": "DataItems[]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

This specification is working correctly. Because I have tried it in Jolt transform demo.

I'm using **JsonTreeReader** for read json in **JoltTransformRecord**. And this is my **input schema**;

```
{
    "name": "Items",
    "namespace": "Items",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "uuid",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "componentId",
            "type": "string"
        },
        {
            "name": "Samples",
            "type": ["null", {
                "type": "map",
                "values": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "name": "SamplesDataItem",
                        "type": "record",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "dataItemId",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "sequence",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "value",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "subType",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "sampleRate",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "statistic",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "duration",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "sampleCount",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "compositionId",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "resetTriggered",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Events",
            "type": ["null", {
                "type": "map",
                "values": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "name": "EventsDataItem",
                        "type": "record",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "dataItemId",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "sequence",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "value",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "subType",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "compositionId",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "resetTriggered",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        {
            "name": "Condition",
            "type": ["null", {
                "type": "map",
                "values": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "name": "ConditionDataItem",
                        "type": "record",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "dataItemId",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "timestamp",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "type",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "sequence",
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "subType",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "nativeCode",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "nativeSeverity",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "qualifier",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "statistic",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "compositionId",
                                "type": ["null", "string"]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using **JsonRecordSetWriter** for write converted result in **JoltTransformRecord**. And this is my **output schema**;

```
{
    "name": "Items",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "Items",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "DataItems",
            "type": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "name": "DataItems",
                    "type": "record",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "name": "uuid",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "componentId",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "eventType",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "type",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "dataItemId",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "timestamp",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "value",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "name",
                            "type": ["null", "string"],
                            "default": null
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "subType",
                            "type": ["null", "string"],
                            "default": null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Since your input and output is JSON, have you tried the original JoltTransformJson processor? If that doesn't work either then there might be a bug in the JOLT library, if it does work there might be a bug in the JoltTransformRecord processor.

Comment: JoltTransformJson is working correctly without any error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in the record handling utilities, I have written [NIFI-6105](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6105) to cover the fix. Good catch!

As a workaround, since you have JSON as input and output, you can use JoltTransformJson instead of JoltTransformRecord. Alternatively, if you know the keys in the map (`PathFeedrate`, e.g.), you can change the schema to treat it as a record rather than a map, that might get you around the bug.

Comment: I have used JoltTransformJson. Thank you so much!